# Good source code browser for C

Tags: c

I am on the look out for a good software for browsing kernel level code written in C. I am currently using source navigator. Are there any better suggestions?

EDIT: I work on systems with both Windows and Linux (Ubuntu), so it should run on at least one of them, but Linux software is preferable.

Comment: Under what operating system ?

Answer (score 3):

This might not be what you're shooting for; it's less interactive than a dedicated tool, but I've found [LXR](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr/) to be very useful for providing a web interface front-end for browsing large source repositories.  In each file, every symbol is linked to its original definition, so it's easy to dial down to exactly what you're looking for.

It was originally designed for indexing the Linux kernel source, and still does so [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/), (though I must say I'm not jazzed about the new AJAX interface...)

It can be run on any code base, though; not limited to the Linux kernel.  And the web interface makes it easy to access from anywhere and from any system.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Slick Edit does the trick for me.
Good tagging for big code bases, building, macros,light ui and support for many languages.
Unfortunately costs some $.

Comment: Does the "Visual" indicate that it is an addon for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) when I receive a big lump of code that I need to do a quick review on. You can use a special syntax in your source to make the doxygen output nice, but it does a decent job without.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I mostly wanted to switch from source navigator was that the project had closed down and the new project ([Source navigator NG](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/sourcenav/))seemed to be defunct(because the website etc. were down). But today, I checked and they had releases upto 2010. So they are probably still up and running.

Check it out, it has a good GUI and searching is easier than in cscope.

Answer (score 0):

netbeans works perfect for me
ctrl+click on any symbol will take you to the definition
then alt+left 
very convenient for source code navigation
it's also cross platform